# Execute SQL Script within Solution Explorer in VS 2008 Professional

Tags: sql, visual-studio

Does anybody know how I can execute a .sql file from within solution explorer in VS 2008 Professional?

I know you can do this in VS 2005 but cannot find this feature in VS 2008 professional

Answer (score 0):

If it's within a database project, then you can right click on it and choose "Run" or "Run On...".

Comment: I have a database project. But I dont get the "Run" option in the menu. I have Visual Studio 2008 Professional. I am not sure it matters.  I also dont see that "Database reference" the MSDN is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Server Explorer" (Ctrl+W, L) to add a connection, then once a connection is open you can right-click the server node and select "New Query". This will allow you to paste in the contents of an SQL file.

Alternatively open the SQL file, then from the "T-SQL Editor" toolbar you can choose "Connect" from your saved connections, and then select the database in the drop-down box.

Comment: Where is the "T-SQl Editor" toolbar?

Comment: Go to "View" -> "Toolbars" and select "T-SQL Editor".

Comment: What version is VS 2008 do you have? I do not see it in my list.

Comment: Does "T-SQL Editor" come with the defualt install?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa833241(v=vs.100).aspx) you go to menu Data->Transact-SQL Editor->New Query Connection I think you can figure out the rest by yourselves.